# Background random image is not automatically refreshed in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have got a `Map` page which has got background `Image`, source of image is set to random image api

```
<Image x:Name="backgroundImage" Source="https://someImageApi" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
```

I would like to refresh the image without any button click in Xamarin Forms. I have tried something below, but this is not working.

```
public Map()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MessagingCenter.Send(this, "RefreshSchedulePage");
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Map>(this, "RefreshSchedulePage", async (sender) =>
        {
            Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new Map(), this);
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        });

    }
```

Comment: By default ImageSource is cached, you can turn it off by setting `CachingEnabled`. You really need to push and pop another page? You cant just set image source to new url?

Comment: @ Shanranm No I don't need to push and pop another page. Could you please advise how can we `turn off` the cachingEnabled via code .?

Answer (score 0):

You should **Subscribe** the notification before you **Send** it

```
InitializeComponent();
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Map>(this, "RefreshSchedulePage", async (sender) =>
 {
    Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new Map(), this);
    await Navigation.PopAsync();
 });
```

And send the message in **OnAppearing**.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `OnPropertyChanged`? (And maybe [`Device.StartTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.starttimer?view=xamarin-forms)? - In case you need a recurring pattern.) `OnPropertyChanged` should draw in all bindings again, meaning it should reach out to the api for the random image again.

```
InitializeComponent();

int interval = 1000;
Device.StartTimer(interval, () => {
    backgroundImage.OnPropertyChanged("Source");
}
```

If you don't need an interval, simply use `OnPropertyChanged` on its own.

Comment: Should probably call propertychanged on MainThread to avoid unexpected crashes